# How to invoke second lambda function with parameter using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to invoke second Lambda function from first lambda function using Python. To invoke I'm using below code snippet:
lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    invoke_response = lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName="teststack",InvocationType='RequestResponse')
```

In that I want to pass two additional parameter, for example: Name and age to the second lambda function, can someone help how I can pass additional parameter to another lambda function and how to receive it in second lambda function.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You have two options. From [the official documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke):

> **ClientContext** (string) -- Using the ClientContext you can pass
>   client-specific information to the Lambda function you are invoking.
>   You can then process the client information in your Lambda function as
>   you choose through the context variable. For an example of a
>   ClientContext JSON, see PutEvents in the Amazon Mobile Analytics API
>   Reference and User Guide .
>
> The ClientContext JSON must be base64-encoded.
>
> **Payload** (bytes or seekable file-like object) -- JSON that you want to
>   provide to your Lambda function as input.

In the Lambda function, the `Payload` is available via the `event` parameter. The `ClientContext` is available via the `context` parameter.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I'm not able to call one lambda function to another lambda function. I'm not getting any error but its keep on loading and its timing out  after 5 minutes. What could be the reason, any idea?

Comment: You probably enabled VPC access on your Lambda function, without adding a NAT gateway to your VPC, so the Lambda function no longer has access to the AWS API. Either remove the Lambda function from the VPC, or add a NAT gateway to your VPC. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188532/why-aws-lambda-within-vpc-can-not-send-message-to-sns