# AWS Lambda hangs on completing lifecycle action

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I use aws lambda to perform custom actions as Auto Scaling terminates instances. It looks like this

```
def scaledown_handler(event, context):
    # customs actions
    client = boto3.client('autoscaling')
    response = client.complete_lifecycle_action(LifecycleHookName=event['detail']['LifecycleHookName'],
                                     LifecycleActionToken=event['detail']['LifecycleActionToken'],
                                     AutoScalingGroupName=event['detail']['AutoScalingGroupName'],
                                     LifecycleActionResult='CONTINUE',
                                     InstanceId=event['detail']['EC2InstanceId'])
```

The problem is that the function just hangs on `client.complete_lifecycle_action()` and finishes by timeout without any response and my ec2 instances are always "Waiting for Terminate Lifecycle Action".

`aws autoscaling complete-lifecycle-action` in aws CLI works fine, but i need to be done this from AWS lambda. How can I find out why does `complete_lifecycle_action()` hang without a response?

Comment: Did you place the Lambda function in a VPC?

Comment: Yes, the Lambda is in the same VPC as my ec2 instances.

Comment: Do you actually need it to be in the VPC? If you don't have a NAT gateway in your VPC then the Lambda function won't have access to anything outside the VPC. The AWS API exists outside your VPC, so the Lambda function is getting a network timeout trying to access it.

Comment: Look at the answers to these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188532/why-aws-lambda-within-vpc-can-not-send-message-to-sns http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35423246/adding-aws-lambda-with-vpc-configuration-causes-timeout-when-accessing-s3

Comment: But as far as I know if I set no VPC for my Lambda it will be run securely inside a default system-managed VPC. My custom actions require connection to one of the ec2 instances  and without VPC I cannot connect to it.

Comment: "But as far as I know if I set no VPC for my Lambda it will be run securely inside a default system-managed VPC" that's incorrect. And like I said, if you require VPC access then you will have to add a NAT gateway to your VPC.

Comment: @MarkB Thanks a lot. I have added a NAT gateway and now it works perfectly. If you want, write a full answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a NAT gateway in your VPC then the Lambda function won't have access to anything outside the VPC. The AWS API exists outside your VPC, so the Lambda function is getting a network timeout trying to access it.

You have to add a NAT Gateway to your VPC in order for Lambda functions (and other things in your VPC that don't have a public IP) to access anything outside the VPC.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use put_lifecycle_hook() API. 
http://www.callumpember.com/auto-scaling-lifecycle-hooks/
On this link, you can get the complete python script for executing the custom actions before terminating the instance.

Comment: I have already created autoscaling lifecycle hook by CLI command `aws autoscaling put-lifecycle-hook`